# Rendered trees look flat

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine

I am working on a small scene you can see below on the render picture. It's almost done, but I have a problem with the trees. They are fully 3D objects, with some textures UV unwrapped.

My problem is, whenever I try and render the image, the trees look super flat, like they are 2D. I have no idea why it does that, I tried rotating them, didn't work, and while it's not that visible if you don't point it out, it still irritates me.

Any idea what could cause this? If you need more information just ask questions I will gladly answer :)

[image: Render picture]

Comment: try to add some lights from the right shining to the left, so that you could see the tree trunk better, then it will look more like 3d

Comment: Just elaborating on the above comment, a three point - back, key, fill - lighting setup could help. The trees on the left with cast shadows have a lot more volume than those on the right, it appears there's only a single light source.

Comment: Also, use the mist pass in compositor, that helps sell the idea of depth

Comment: @Chris Yes this seemed to helped, thank you for your help guys. I would like to mark this as solved, but for some reason I cannot accept any of theese, the button is just not there, so I just edit the title

Comment: @BenjamínFeščák For the sake of completeness you can post as an answer and accept it rather than a comment the actual steps that helped you achieve the desired effect. That may help people that have the same problem as you  find it in the future. Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to add some lights from the right shining to the left, so that you could see the tree trunk better, then it will look more like 3d – Chris